# How to export the values of a SpatRaster into .txt-file using the terra-package?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, r-raster, terra

I got a .tif dataset with land cover classifications (so categorical values) which I want to replace with another value (integers) and export these values into a .txt-file following the ASCII format (this is required by the model I want to use the output for).

**1. Is there any opportunity to export the actual values of the SpatRaster?**

**2. And are there any concerns about exporting to a .txt-file by defining the filename?**

I was able to replace the values by using subst(), but when trying to export I was only able to produce output containing the ID.

```r
r <- rast(nrows=3, ncols=3)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
levels(r) <- cls


replacement <- c(10,20,30)
r_replaced <- subst(r,levels(r)[[1]]$cover, replacement)

writeRaster(r_replaced, "test.txt", filetype = "AAIGrid")
```

The output looks like this

```
ncols        3
nrows        3
xllcorner    -180.000000000000
yllcorner    -90.000000000000
dx           120.000000000000
dy           60.000000000000
NODATA_value 255
 6 4 6
 4 4 4
 4 5 4
```

but I actually want it to look like this

```
ncols        3
nrows        3
xllcorner    -180.000000000000
yllcorner    -90.000000000000
dx           120.000000000000
dy           60.000000000000
NODATA_value 255
 30 10 30
 10 10 10
 10 20 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (note `raw=TRUE`)

```
# levels(r)[[1]][,1] == 1:3

r_replaced <- subst(r, c(1:3), c(10,20,30), raw=TRUE)

writeRaster(r_replaced, "test.asc", NAflag=-999, overwrite=T)
```

Result

```
readLines("test.asc", 10)
# [1] "ncols        3"                
# [2] "nrows        3"                
# [3] "xllcorner    -180.000000000000"
# [4] "yllcorner    -90.000000000000" 
# [5] "dx           120.000000000000" 
# [6] "dy           60.000000000000"  
# [7] "NODATA_value  -999"            
# [8] " 10.0 30 20"                   
# [9] " 10 10 30"                     
#[10] " 10 30 30"
```

The problem with your approach is that `r_replaced` is still a categorical raster (see `levels(r_replaced)` for your code). You can also start out by removing the categories

```
levels(r) <- NULL
```

Although, with this example, you could also do

```
rr <- r * 10
writeRaster(rr, "test.asc", NAflag=-99, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Setting the levels(r) = NULL and then using subst() on the IDs worked out for me! Thanks a lot!